# PHP Wkhtmltopdf will not generate more than 41 pages

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I am generating a file with data represented in a html table. The problem occurs when there is so much data that wkhtmltopdf would need to generate page number 42. It never finishes loading. If there is lets say 5000 elements and that covers exactly 41 pages it'll generate quickly, but if I add another element it wont finish.

I am using a php wrapper. There is not a lot of code...

This is the function that builds the html

```
private function _generate() {
    $_html .= '<table>';
    $_html .= '<tr>';
    $_html .= '<th>Naziv medija</th>';
    $_html .= '</tr>';

    foreach ($this->_model as $value) {
        $_html .= '<tr>';
        $_html .= '<td>' . $value->attributes['naziv'] . '</td>';   
        $_html .= '</tr>';
    }

    $_html .= '</table>';

    return $_html;
}
```

This function then returns the html to the bottom code

```
    $pdf = new WKPDF();
    $pdf->set_html($this->_generate());
    $pdf->set_orientation($orientation);
    $pdf->set_page_size($pagesize);
    $pdf->render();
    $pdf->output($type, $this->_filename);
```

If I generate the html and save it somewhere and then create the pdf through the console there is no problem, it works fine.

Any ideas why i cannot generate more than 41 pages with php?

Comment: Check your webserver error.log What is the error you get? perhaps you're exhausting your memory allocation?

Comment: when you say that it wont finish - what does it do? if it hangs, chances are there is a log somewhere telling you what is going on, turn on error reporting in php if you havent already got it on

Comment: The page keeps loading, nothing hangs it just keeps loading forever

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any solutions?